# C# set clipboard data from class

Tags: multithreading, text, clipboard

i have a public class , in that class i have a void which sets Clipboard.Text and i have a thread from which i call that func, everytime i call it i get

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

I have tried the following :

```
        Thread t = new Thread(Worker);
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
```

But i still recieve error, i even tried [STAThread]
My function looks like this

```
    public void Set(string s)
    {

        Clipboard.SetText(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is telling you put put the `STAThread` attribute on your main function, like so:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    // Your code
}
```

You said you tried STAThread, but was it on the main function or the function you're calling?